# How can I include fields from a superclass in the generated Swagger spec (using Scalatra+Swagger)?

Tags: scala, swagger, scalatra

I have this case class that's extending an abstract class:

```
@ApiModel(description = "A price for an offer.")
case class OfferPrice(
                       override val amount: Double,
                       override val taxAmount: Double,
                       override val taxRate: Option[Double]
                     ) extends Price(amount, taxAmount, taxRate)

abstract class Price(
                      @(ApiModelProperty@field)(description = "The amount.") val amount: Double,
                      @(ApiModelProperty@field)(description = "The tax amount.") val taxAmount: Double,
                      @(ApiModelProperty@field)(description = "The tax rate.") val taxRate: Option[Double]
                    )
```

Exciting stuff, right? My problem is that the definition in the generated swagger.json file looks like this:

```
"OfferPrice": {
  "properties": {

  }
}
```

It's not including the fields from the abstract class. How can I include those fields as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work because fields and annotations declared in the super class are hidden by fields overridden in the subclass.

I think this is correct definition of your model:

```
@ApiModel(description = "A price for an offer.")
case class OfferPrice(
  @ApiModelProperty(description = "The amount.") amount: Double,
  @ApiModelProperty(description = "The tax amount.") taxAmount: Double,
  @ApiModelProperty(description = "The tax rate.") taxRate: Option[Double]
) extends Price(amount, taxAmount, taxRate)

abstract class Price(
  amount: Double,
  taxAmount: Double,
  taxRate: Option[Double]
)
```

but description of model and properties is not rendered in Scalatra's Swagger 2.0 support currently. It will be supported in the future release. See: https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/issues/684

Comment: Thank you for the help on Gitter! Could you edit your post here to include the solution? Then I'll accept the answer :)